# Selecting multiple dates across one simultaneous touch of calendar in android

Tags: android, calendar, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I want to create a custom calendar in which user can select multiple dates while touching from one start date to another end date in one move.

[image]

something like u can see in the image above. How to achieve this? any idea or source please suggest. Thanks in advance !! :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I'm sorry but android CalendarView doesn't support this feature. You can't select multiple dates in it.
Maybe you should look for some kind of third party library to do that.

Comment: then how to get dates selected during the touch event in onTouch()? please give more clarity on this. thanks !

Comment: I'm sorry but my answer was wrong, I already edited it. Android native CalendarView doesn't support that feature, you can't select multiple dates.